# What is the difference between model and entity in MVC pattern?

Tags: java, mysql, model-view-controller

Suppose I have an entity like Student and using MVC pattern I make a Student Model in my project. But there are certain times when I create a table I get foreign key of another entity. (One to many relationship - Student Borrow Book)
So when I create Book Model I have to include foreign key as an attribute of the Book class. So does it violate the MVC pattern? 
Please help. 
How can I implement this using MVC ?

Comment: no including foreign key as an attribute does not violate MVC pattern. The term entity usually comes up while creating entity relationship diagram. Model is the M in MVC. In your example Student would refer to both an Entity and you would also have a Model if you follow MVC for implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, It does not violate MVC.

By definition, "Model" in MVC means logical representation of data in application. Building relationship between entity(in your case, Student and Book) is a way to represent student's information.

Say, I am building a web application on "School Library".

1. Entity(Student and Book) relationship will be all part of "model".
2. Now, there is web portal (or simply a web page) where student can check book he has borrowed, is a "view".
3. Classes(logic written to fetch data from model and render it to view) that connect Model and View are written in "Controller".

Check web framework like Django, Laravel. They follow MVC paradigm to build complex web applications.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So if I include a String id of Student in BookModel.java class that won't be a problem? IS it ok to include another model inside a model class as an attribute?

Comment: It most definitely does violate the model as described. There is no "foreign key" in a book.

Comment: @Parker, a model should reflect the world it describes. Does a book have a student, or does a student have books?

Comment: Do not put String id, instead use another model inside a model as an attribute. Look for how to define onetoone, manytomany and onetomany attributes (choose what suites your requirement)

Answer (score 1):

Let's back up. "MVC" is "Model-View-Controller"; each of the three is a distinct part. The model, the subject of your question, is the part that describes the world of your program. The model comprises the nouns, adjectives, and verbs of your problem space, or "domain of discourse". Only use nouns, adjectives, and verbs that belong to the domain. That structure of domain-relevant types that represent the actors or entities (nouns) with their attributes (nouns and adjectives), and behaviors (verbs) is your model.

In your domain you mentioned two nouns and a verb. "Student borrows Book". Now I've never met a student who had a foreign key. (Unless it was to their exchange-student girl friend's apartment.) Nor a book. So "foreign key" is not a part of the model.

Here's a model:

```
public interface Person {
  String getName();
}

public interface Borrower<T> {
  void borrow(T thing);
}

public interface Replacer<T> {
  void replace (T thing);
}

public class Student implements Person,
    Borrower<Book>, Replacer<Book> {
  private final Set<Book> bookshelf = new HashSet<>();

  public Collection<Book> getBookshelf() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(bookshelf);
  }

  // more implementation
}
```

I purposely decomposed the model into single-abstract-method (SAM) interfaces. The `Person` interface would not be one typically, though. The action methods, transitive verbs like "borrow" and "replace", should be SAM interfaces, in part to support lambdas, in part to keep your model clear and simple to work with.